# how can I create a data frame containing all the combinations of a column?pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

how can I create a data frame containing all the combinations a column(eg. Usage) value for a specific group (eg. userid) in a data frame using pandas python?

for example:
if this is the data frame I have,

```
user-id      serial-number       value     day

1   2   10      1
1   2   20      2
1   2   30      3
1   2   40      4
1   2   50      5
1   2   60      6
1   2   70      7
1   2   80      8
1   2   90      9
1   2   100    10
1   2   200    11
1   2   300    12
1   2   400    13
2   3   11      1
2   3   12      2
2   3   13      3
2   3   14      4
2   3   15      5
2   3   16      6
2   3   17      7
2   3   18      8
```

I need the resultant dataframe to be:
(combinations for the first value in the "value" column)

```
user-id     serial-number       value       value1      day

1   2   10  10    1
1   2   10  20    1
1   2   10  30    1
1   2   10  40    1
1   2   10  50    1
1   2   10  60    1
1   2   10  70    1
1   2   10  80    1
1   2   10  90    1 
1   2   10  100   1 
1   2   10  200   1 
1   2   10  300   1
1   2   10  400   1
.
.
.

2   3   11  11    1
2   3   11  12    1
2   3   11  13    1
2   3   11  14    1
2   3   11  15    1
2   3   11  16    1
2   3   11  17    1
2   3   11  18    1
```

similarly i want to do it for all the values in the "value" column.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: sorry that the example is not clear. Basically I need rows added to the data frame with all the combinations of a particular column value in the data frame!

Comment: You can print your table as preformatted text by adding four spaces to the start of each line; check the formatting help for details. I'd edit it for you, but it looks like your first table is also missing a column.

Comment: Do you want to copy From Value Column of First Dataframe to the Value Column of Second Data frame ? or what was the question. It seems unclear....

Comment: Now I guess the dataset and the expected output is clear?

Comment: I had an solution for this from someone and its not there now, could someone explain me why please?

Answer (score 0):

```
subset = pd.DataFrame()

for _, i in test1.groupby(['user-id']):

                vals = i['value']
                val, val1 = zip(*product(vals, vals))
                vals_len = len(vals)

                def elongate(s, k):

                    return pd.concat([s] * k, ignore_index=True)

                res = pd.DataFrame({'user-id': i['user-id'].pipe(elongate, vals_len),
                                    'serial-number': i['serial-number'].pipe(elongate, vals_len),
                                    'value': i['value'].pipe(elongate, vals_len),
                                    'day': i['day'].pipe(elongate, vals_len),
                                    'value': val,
                                    'value1': val1
                                   })


                subtest = subtest.append(res)


print(subtest)
```

This Worked for me  perfectly.

Comment: This works fine for a smaller data set, but for a dataset with 220625 records, it is very slow. Any better solution which is fast is much appreciated.  Any suggestions?